# Delete variations from 'simple' products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Some of my 'simple' still have variations, I want to delete all existing variations from product with product type 'simple'.

I have created the following sql statement, but I am not sure if this is correct.

I also am struggling to create a delete statement for this.

select * from wp_posts, wp_term_relationships where post_parent = object_id AND term_taxonomy_id =17 and post_type = 'product_variation' ;

Thanks for your help.

Comment: term_taxonomy_id =17 is 'simple'

Comment: I go the statement..

delete p from wp_posts p INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON p.post_parent = r.object_id AND r.term_taxonomy_id =17 and p.post_type = 'product_variation' ;

Comment: I now wan't to know if this is the right way for doing this.